# Python package contains both MANIFEST and MANIFEST.in - do I gitignore MANIFEST?

Tags: python, github, manifest, package

When including external files in a python package I define it in MANIFEST.in as

**MANIFEST.in**

```
include aikif/web_app/static/*
```

and building the package will produce a **MANIFEST** file as

```
#file GENERATED by distutils, do NOT edit
README.txt
setup.py
aikif\__init__.py
aikif\bias.py
aikif\cls_file_mapping.py
...
```

At the moment I am including both MANIFEST and MANIFEST.in in the github repository but have not seen other repositories include both.

Should I git ignore MANIFEST, or is there a better way to build the package so it isn't needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - yes, include the MANIFEST file in your .gitignore

The Python package page doesnt mention ignoring MANIFEST (http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/everything.html)

```
# Compiled python modules.
*.pyc

# Setuptools distribution folder.
/dist/

# Python egg metadata, regenerated from source files by setuptools.
/*.egg-info
/*.egg
```

Found a good example on github ( pypa / pip ) https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/.gitignore which does include the MANIFEST in the .gitignore

```
build/
dist/
docs/_build/
pip.egg-info/
MANIFEST
.tox
*.egg
*.py[cod]
*~
.coverage
coverage.xml
```

Many other packages on github dont have the file ignored, but it isnt in the repository either so I assume people just have it listed when they do a git status from their local repo.